# Jquery calendar plug in not working

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, datepicker

I'm using the [JDPicker](http://jdpicker.paulds.fr/?p=doc) plugin but this is not working.

I added those three tags in head tag:

```
     <script type ="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
     <script type ="text/javascript" src="jquery.jdpicker.js"></script>
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="jdpicker.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
```

then added the following code in body:

```
 <input type="text" name="your_input" class="jdpicker" />
 <input type="hidden" name="your_input_2" class="jdpicker" />
```

I am able to see the text-box but when I click, there is not pop-up calendar coming. I even want a date to assign to a variable when I select a particular date.

Comment: do you see any javascript errors..?

Comment: Why don't you try out the date picker already available with the JQuery UI http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/ . This really wont give you trouble and would be good!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to implement it locally and it works on my side. Here's the code I use:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type ="text/javascript" src="jquery.jdpicker.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="jdpicker.css" type="text/css" />
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#test1').jdPicker();
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body class='default'>
   <input class="jdpicker" style="width: 200px; height: 25px;" id="#test1" />
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: :It is not working on my facebook iframe app and how do i get the selected value.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add following also:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.jdpicker').jdPicker(); 
});
</script>
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

You have to load it first as mentioned in a previous post.
I'd also recommend the [JQuery UI Datepicker](http://jqueryui.com/) as an alternative

Answer (score 0):

I have a better answer for you. You did directly copy paste the above content given in the website but did you see whether JQuery is really added or not. I did not find any file named 
`jquery.js`.

This means that your project does not have JQuery with it: download the mentionned .js file, include it in your project and it will work. Change the first line of your external JS and point it to the downloaded JQuery file.

Rather I would suggest you to try out the [JQuery UI datepicker](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/)

It would be helpful